On Linux ubuntu, unmet dependencies after failed update, laptop can't boot
After updating and running out-of-battery, my wife's laptop with Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS doesn't boot anymore, I get a "Oh no, something went wrong" white screen. When getting the GNU Grub menu and picking the recovery mode, I first tried the dpkg Repair broken packages option but get some logs about dependencies issues.
Next on the root shell, I have tried the following prompts:
sudo apt update
I get :
/usr/lib/apt/method/http: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.8: cannot shared object file: No such file or directory 8 times before a method http has died unexpectedly / Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
sudo apt --fix-broken install
Not working, I get the error mentioned above a lot more and a list of unmet dependencies (around 30 packages)
dpkg --force-all --configure- a
Following a post in the superuser forum that seems close to my issue
dpkg --purge --force-depends libnettles8 which return that the request is ignored since libnettle8 isn't installed.
Is there a way to fix all broken dependencies at once while preserving the data on the hard drive?
If not, what would be the easiest way?
I am very much new to the Linux ecosystem and lack very much any solid basis although I'm willing to learn.
Thank you very much for your help!

Libnettle seemed to be istalled and many other packages were still causing problems too. By lack of a better option, I ended up flashing a live-usb, backup the data and proceed to reinstall of the latest Ubuntu version (24.04). I have seen it was possible to reinstall without loss of data but I must've done something wrong and wiped up the data entirely during the reinstall and haven't figured out why.


Following a post in the superuser forum that seems close to my issue dpkg --purge --force-depends libnettles8 which return that the request is ignored since libnettle8 isn't installed.

As the previous apt error message says, the problem is that libnettle8 isn't installed – you don't need to purge it, you need to install it. (Most likely the power was lost while the libnettle update was being unpacked.)
Download the .deb from https://packages.ubuntu.com/libnettle8 (make sure to select the right distribution and then the correct architecture, usually amd64 – not arm64!), then carry it over on a USB stick and install it with dpkg -i. Repeat for other libraries that may be missing.

Hello! Thank you for your time and answer. I have tried to install the missing libnettle8 via usb but get the following error:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration
libnettle8t64:i386 (3.9.1-2.2build1.1) breaks libnettle8 (<< 3.9.1-2.2build1.1) and is installed
Version of libnettle8:amd64 to be configured is 3.7.3-1build2

Then I guess you need to re-install libnettle8t64 instead of libnettle8 (they both have the same .so but different variants).
